# Histogram in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I've some problem with my code in R Shiny. When I run my code, the error comes with `Error:'x' must be numeric`. This is my code at server.R

```
library(shiny)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
shinyServer(function(input, output) {


     output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    malaria = input$malaria
    i = 'a'


     if(input$p=='a'){
      i<4
    }

    if(input$p=='b'){
      i<-5
    }


    postM    <-malaria[,4]

    bins <- seq(0, 100, length.out =1)
    hist(postM, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
})


For ui.R

   library(shiny)

    malaria <- read.csv("file:///C:/Users/Bella/Desktop/malaria/Malaria2/data/malaria.csv",header=FALSE)
year <- malaria$year

ui <- fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Rate Death of Malaria"),

     sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(

      radioButtons("radio", label = h3("Select the sample of countries"),
                   choices = list("Bangladdesh", "China","Ethiopia","South Africa",
                                  "Indonesia","India", "Kenya","Cambodia"," Myanmmar","Malaysia","Nigeria","Somalia","Thailand"),
                   selected = "World"),

      selectInput("vertical","Show vertical line in year(s):", 
                  choices = unique(malaria$year),multiple=TRUE
      ),

      checkboxInput("hor", "Show horizontal axis", TRUE)

    ),

    mainPanel(

      plotOutput("lineChart")
    )   
  )      
)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Try creating a simpler program that recreates the problem. Comment out parts of your code and replace with temporary stubs. This will show you where the problem is occurring. It looks like you are trying to convert on non-numeric string to a number somewhere. View the input to that conversion and see what it is getting that is non-numeric.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't so much an Shiny problem as it is a formatting issue for your data-type. Try running:

```
typeof(postM)
```

It's likely it will return "character" and the hist() function prefers numbers ("double" would be a good variable type for the histogram input)

If it's simply a matter of formatting the .csv data, you can try:

```
hist(as.numeric(postM))
```

or:

```
hist(as.numeric(unlist(postM)))
```

However, it's important to make sure that your data should be converted into a numeric value, rather than coerce the format before taking a look at the source data.

Hope that helps!